# Re: Count value of cells in one column that are within a specific date range in another

Tags: excel, formula

Hope you guys can help me please :)

I am trying to create a profit/loss sheet that automatically counts the values in all cells in AH that are within a specific month...

What is the best way to go about this please? Any ideas?

Comment: (The date column is W, format: 06/09/17) TIA

Answer (score 0):

I thing the following formula might work for you:

`=SUMPRODUCT((MONTH(A1:A60)=2)*C1:C60)`

Where `A` is the date and `C` is the value that needs to be counted.